# For a given and unique string how to find all corresponding strings

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, uniq

```
# cat lun.txt
/dev/sdb 60002ac00000000000000f0f0000799d
/dev/sdc 60002ac00000000000000fdb0000799d
/dev/sdd 60002ac00000000000000f0f0000799d
/dev/sde 60002ac00000000000000fdb0000799d
#
```

How do I list all devices for a given WWID, like below:

```
60002ac00000000000000f0f0000799d 
    /dev/sdb
    /dev/sdd
60002ac00000000000000fdb0000799d
    /dev/sdc
    /dev/sde
```

I have tried using sort, uniq and awk. But no luck

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
$ awk '{ device[$2]=device[$2]"\n"$1 } END{ for(i in device) print i,device[i] }' lun.txt
60002ac00000000000000fdb0000799d 
/dev/sdc
/dev/sde
60002ac00000000000000f0f0000799d 
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdd
```

- `device[$2]=device[$2]"\n"$1` creates an array `device` indexed by the wwid, `$2` appends the `$1`, first column with the array element
- `for(i in device) print i,device[i]` prints the content of the array

Answer (score 0):

I just added a tab(\t) to get the desired output.

```
awk '{ device[$2]=device[$2]"\n\t"$1 } END{ for(i in device) print i,device[i] }' lun.txt
60002ac00000000000000fdb0000799d
        /dev/sdc
        /dev/sde
60002ac00000000000000f0f0000799d
        /dev/sdb
        /dev/sdd
```